# central management system across domains

Tags: php, content-management-system, yii, dns, cross-domain

My goal is to have 1 centralized place for the Application + DB and all the domains will serve pages from that place (without copying all the files)

My goal is to eliminate the need to copy my app to 5 different domains, and everythime there is a new feature an update 5 is needed on 5 different places.

I checked this: [accessing files across domains that are hosted on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447184/accessing-files-across-domains-that-are-hosted-on-the-same-server), but it didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the domains are on the same physical server this can be accomplished.

Your code will reside outside the web root:

- domain1
- domain2
- domain3
- domain4
- domain5
- common_yii
- - framework ( the yii framework files )
- - appDir ( your web app files go here )
- - - protected
- - - - config ( your app config file 'main.php' should be here )

your index.php in each of the domains should look something like this:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii = '../common_yii/framework/yii.php';
$config = '../common_yii/appDir/protected/config/main.php';


// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
if ( !isset( Yii::app()->params ) ) {
    Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
}
```

you will be able to set instance specific variables in the index.php for each domain.

HTH

Comment: wow! hope it works...i'll give it a try - just 1 thing: having files outside of the webroot is not a security breach? @nvwd

Comment: Not at all. The index.php includes what it needs to process the request. If anything I believe it is safer since your config and logic files are not accessible directly from the browser.

Comment: Hi again - I setup everything like you said but i'm getting and internal server error, can it be related to linux permissions?

Comment: any other info on the error? permissions can cause issues but I would hope the server would respond with a better error message

Comment: Thanks, called the support and then found my problem:
$yii = '/../common_yii/framework/yii.php';
$config = '/../common_yii/appDir/protected/config/main.php';

I was missing a '/' :)

Comment: glad to hear you got it sorted out ;-}